# Consolidated cond arguments in Clojure (CL style)

Tags: clojure, lisp, conditional-statements, common-lisp

In Clojure I do this

```
(println (cond false "don't care" "otherwise" "otherwise"))
```

In Common LISP this would be

```
(print (cond (nil "don't care") ("otherwise") ))
```

Is there a way to get this kind of simplified `cond` in Clojure?

Comment: Idiomatic would be: (println (cond false "don't care" :else "otherwise")). Why would you want the CL version?

Comment: Short answer - translating CL to Clojure. It appears to be idiomatic CL to have a 10-line statement for the truth test that *also* returns a result. (ie consolidated).

Comment: That Common Lisp form does not work as you seem to expect.

Comment: Svante, how so? It returns "don't care" if `false` is false and "otherwise" otherwise. What do you think hawkeye expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version which includes a fix for that Alex Taggart noticed below. Passes all the test cases shown in the test. It allows for arbitrary clauses passed to `my-cond` to be length 1 instead of 2 which results in the length 1 clause being both the test for truthiness and the result if it is true. Based off my limited experience with CL I actually think this behavior is different from what `cond` does but seems to be in line with how I've interpreted what you're asking for.  Kotarak's answer seems to line up with the CL one as using the last statement in the CL `cond` seems to match up with using the `:else` clause in the Clojure version.

Regardless here is a solution where it should allow any clause to be a length of one and use that for both the truth test and result.

```
(defmacro my-cond
  [& others]
  (if others
    (let [more# (next others)
          extra-clauses# (if more# `(my-cond ~@more#))
          clause# (first others)]
      (if (= 2 (count clause#))
        `(if ~(first clause#) ~(second clause#) ~extra-clauses#)
        `(if ~(first clause#) ~(first clause#)  ~extra-clauses#)))))


(deftest my-cond-works
  (is (= 3 (my-cond (false 1) (false 2) (3))))
  (is (= "otherwise" (my-cond (false "don't care") ("otherwise"))))
  (is (= nil (my-cond (:one nil) ("otherwise"))))
  (is (= "care" (my-cond (1 "care") ("otherwise"))))
  (is (= "otherwise" (my-cond (false "care") ("otherwise") (true "true"))))
  (is (= "silly" (my-cond (nil "no") (nil) ("yes" "silly")))))
```

I'd really advise translating the CL over to the Clojure form of `cond`. I would place the mental overhead of allowing the CL syntax along with the Clojure syntax in the same project as not worth saving time in translating it now. Looking at the code in the future after becoming used to how Clojure's `cond` and trying to remember why the other syntax is there seems not worth the time saved by not translating.

Below version fails as Alex Taggart says below. Keeping it here so his comment makes sense.
The below version does:

```
(defmacro my-cond [[if1 then1] & others]
  (when (or if1 then1 others)
    (let [extra-clauses# (if others `(my-cond ~@others))]
      (if then1
        `(if ~if1 ~then1 ~extra-clauses#)
        `(if ~if1 ~if1  ~extra-clauses#)))))

user> (my-cond (false "first") (nil nil) ("otherwise"))
"otherwise"
```

Comment: The problem with using destructuring is that you lose the ability to distinguish between absence and nil, which matters in this case.  E.g., `(my-cond (:else nil))` should return nil.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I've added a version which handles this. I actually think I've gone to far in my interpretation of what hawkeye was asking by allowing the single element form from the CL version to be anywhere instead of just as the else clause. Going to leave it how it is though. Probably should have played around in a CL repl before attempting this.

Comment: This version of my-cond has an bug, it evaluates the if1 part twice in some situations. So side effections happen twice.  The CL version of cond assures that the side effections happen only once in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the clojure version was intended to have fewer parens. You can certainly write your own cond-ish macro to do what you want.

Here is a simple implementation (i.e. does not implement the full CL version)...

```
(defmacro my-cond [[if1 then1] & others]
  (if others 
    `(if ~if1 ~then1 (my-cond ~@others))
    `(if ~if1 ~then1)))
```

And you can then...

```
(my-cond (false 1) (false 2) (3 3))   ; results in 3
```

Comment: What I actually want would be  (my-cond (false 1) (false 2) (3))   ; results in 3

Answer (score 0):

An important feature of the CL `cond` is that if any of the operands of `cond` is a singleton, then the element within the singelton is evaluated, and if that value is non-nil, it is returned without evaluating it a second time.

```lisp
(cond
   (a 100)
   ((f 1 2 3))
   (b 200))
```

This form evaluates to 100 if `a` is true, else to the value of `(f 1 2 3)` if that is non-nil, else to 200 if `b` is non-nil, else to `nil`.

I believe what you need is the following.

```clj
(defmacro my-cond [[if1 & then1] & others]
  (when (or if1 then1 others)
    (let [extra-clauses# (if others `(cl-cond ~@others))]
      (if then1
        `(if ~if1 (do ~@then1) ~extra-clauses#)
        `(or ~if1 ~extra-clauses#)))))
```